# How to calculate the difference between current alerts and alerts minute ago

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana, promql

I want to use a query in Prometheus to calculate the difference between ALERT now and ALERT a minute ago. In order to then display it in Grafana and understand the dynamics. If the value is negative, then the alerts are reduced, if the value is positive, then vice versa.
I tried the following request, but it gives the wrong thing.

```
count_over_time(ALERTS{job="m60"}[2m])-count_over_time(ALERTS{job="m60"}[1m])
```

Please tell me which function to use in the request. Or the right way. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to user [offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier):

```
ALERTS{job="m60"} - (ALERTS{job="m60"} offset 1m)
```